# Stdout to both pipe and console?

Tags: unix, pipe, stdout, tee

Is there a way to output to both stdout and to the stdin of another process? That is, have the intermediate stdout be output before it reaches the pipe of the other process?

I know of the [tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) command lets you write to a file and to stdout, but I don't want any files involved here.

Comment: `tee` *is* writing to std-out, which would be read by the next `|`'s stdin. Or am I misunderstanding your Q?

Comment: @shellter - right. I want it to go to the pipe and the old stdout (ie console display)

Answer (score 2):

This is a little "hacky" I guess, but you can redirect the output of `tee` to `stderr`. Since most programs take input from `stdin`, redirecting to `stderr` will leave the original output as is while still piping through to the next process.

For example,

```
cat file.txt | tee >&2 | wc -l
```

Will output the entire contents of file.txt, and *then* output just the number of lines (`wc -l`) in file.txt.

Obviously this will only work if stderr outputs where you want it to (like the terminal/console).

Not an ideal solution since it involves using `stderr` for something it's not necessarily made for but it works.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I found another solution (just write a program to do it...), but this will be useful for people coming here later.